# add comment in XML root element python code

Tags: python, xml

I am parsing data from csv to xml using Python library import `xml.etree.ElementTree`.
I want to put a comment before first node so the output will be like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Comment -->
<a xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <b>
      <c>xxxxx</c>
   </b>
</a>
```

The code I have try is:

```py
from lxml import etree
import xml.dom.minidom
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

name_space = {
            # namespace defined below
            "xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        }
comment = et.Comment
root = et.Element('')
root.tag = None
root.insert(0, comment)
root2 = et.Element('a', namespace)
root.insert(1, root2)
xml_data = et.tostring(root, encoding='iso-8859-1', method='xml')
xmlstr = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xml_data, parser=None).toprettyxml(indent="   ", encoding='iso-8859-1')
```

Last sentence `xml.dom.minidom.parseString()` gives me the error `xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: junk after document element: line 2, column 135`

If I print xml_data content it is:

```
<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'iso-8859-1\'?>\n<!--Comment--><a xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" /><b><c>xxxx</c></b>
```

Do you know if is there any other way to add the comment?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're making it a bit too complicated. Try something like the below. Note that this assumes (like in your question) that `xxxxx` has already been extract from the csv file.

```
cmt = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<a xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<!-- Comment -->
   <b>
      <c>xxxxx</c>
   </b>
</a>
"""

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_comments=False)
doc = etree.XML(cmt.encode(),parser=parser)
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

The output should be what you're looking for.